# How to select first option in a select box after appending options by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box in a modal where I am appending options using jQuery. I want the first option to be selected after appending all item. I have tried some but no luck. Here are my attempts below.

My select box in modal:

```
<select id="modal_cmbSection" name="modal_cmbSection" class="form-control required">
</select>
```

My jQuery code where appending and trying to set selected first option:

```
var sectionOption = "";
var $sectionSelect = $('#modal_cmbSection');
$sectionSelect.empty();
$(".section-block").each(function() {
    var eachSectionName = $(this).find(".section-section-name").val();
    sectionOption = "<option>" + eachSectionName + "</option>";
    $sectionSelect.append(sectionOption);
});
$sectionSelect.find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: don't you need "attr" instead of "prop"?

Comment: Your code should work. https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/247/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki my code doesn't work. The select box is in a modal. When I click a button the modal is opened. can this  be a issue?

Comment: Should works in the modal too @SumonBappi .. http://jsfiddle.net/GG9Sa/3615/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes it works fine. there's another function called ResetInput. which I did not notice before. Actually My code was right. Sorry to all of you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this,

```
var sectionOption = "";
var $sectionSelect = $('#modal_cmbSection');
$sectionSelect.empty();
$(".section-block").each(function() {
    var eachSectionName = $(this).find(".section-section-name").val();
    sectionOption = "<option>" + eachSectionName + "</option>";
    $sectionSelect.append(sectionOption);
});
//set selected as true for first option
$("#modal_cmbSection option:first-child").attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is pretty much the same as what the OP is already using (although the OPs uses `prop()` so is slightly better practice). If that doesn't work, there's no reason this will. The issue must lay elsewhere.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$sectionSelect.find( 'option:first' ).prop( 'selected', true );
```